# Trying to implement Picard iterations in Python

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to write code to implement [Picard's iterations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) in Python. Specially, I want to plot the appoximations at each step of the iteration. This is what I've got after a long day of trying.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# Define the function f(u, t)
def f(u, t):
    return u

# Define the iteration function
def iterations(f, N, t_0, u_0, T, h):
    num_steps = int((T - t_0) / h)
    t = np.linspace(t_0, T, num_steps)

    # Compute the exact solution using odeint
    u_exact = odeint(f, u_0, t)
    plt.plot(t, u_exact, c = 'k', label="Exact solution")

    u = u_0*np.ones(num_steps)  # Initialize u
    
    # Perform iterations using the trapezoidal rule
    for j in range(0, N):
      plt.plot(t, u, label=f"Iteration {j}")
      integrand = lambda t: f(u, t)
      for i in range(num_steps):
          integral_result, _ = quad(integrand, t_0, t[i])
          u[i] = u_0 + integral_result


    plt.xlabel("t")
    plt.ylabel("u")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

iterations(f, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0.01)
```

The specific error I get here is `only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 35>()
33     plt.show()
34
---> 35 iterations(f, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0.01)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_quadpack_py.py in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
575     if points is None:
576         if infbounds == 0:
--> 577             return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
578         else:
579             return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

What I'm trying to do is to record on `u[i]` the value that corresponds to `u(t_i)` where the `u` in the code is actually the j-th iteration in the math.

Comment: Show the full 'specific error'.  Where the error occurs is just as important as what it says.  The smarted ones of us may be able to deduce the where, but it's better if we don't have to guess.  Besides, you might learn something by paying attention to the specific place (and function and/or arguments involved).

Comment: `quad` integrates a scalar value funciton.   Your `integrand` returns an array the size of `u`, which is not scalar.  It's always a good idea to test function you supply to these `scipy` functions to make sure it fits the requirements.  It is `quad` itself that's complaining.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, both for the comment on showing the full error (I'll have it in mind for future posts) and figuring out precisely where there's a problem. I guess one way to fix this would be to look for an integration that takes arrays as inputs?

Comment: @hamath you can edit your question to add the full error to reopen your question

Answer (score 1):

The full error message

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 35
     32     plt.legend()
     33     plt.show()
---> 35 iterations(f, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0.01)

Cell In[1], line 26, in iterations(f, N, t_0, u_0, T, h)
     24   integrand = lambda t: f(u, t)
     25   for i in range(num_steps):
---> 26       integral_result, _ = quad(integrand, t_0, t[i])
     27       u[i] = u_0 + integral_result
     30 plt.xlabel("t")

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_quadpack_py.py:463, in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst, complex_func)
    460     return retval
    462 if weight is None:
--> 463     retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
    464                    points)
    465 else:
    466     if points is not None:

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_quadpack_py.py:575, in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    573 if points is None:
    574     if infbounds == 0:
--> 575         return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    576     else:
    577         return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

So the error occurs in the `quad()` call, several layers down.  The last layer is a compiled function, so doesn't give more details.

But if I test the `integrand` function by itself

```
In [4]: f(np.ones(3),0)
Out[4]: array([1., 1., 1.])
```

it returns an array the same size as the `u` argument.

If I try to convert that to a `float` I get your error message

```
In [6]: float(f(np.ones(3),0))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 1
----> 1 float(f(np.ones(3),0))

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I have the advantage of having seen this kind of error in other `quad` uses.  But `quad` docs are clear that it only integrates a scalar valued function.